# Setting a breakpoint in RubyMine causes "no implicit conversion from nil to integer" when the debugger is run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, breakpoints, jetbrains-ide, rubymine

Steps to reproduce

1. Start RubyMine

```text
RubyMine 2022.2.3
Build #RM-222.4345.14, built on October 5, 2022
Runtime version: 17.0.4.1+7-b469.62 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 12.6
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 8
Metal Rendering is ON
Registry:
    debugger.watches.in.variables=false

Non-Bundled Plugins:
    com.intellij.ideolog (203.0.30.0)
    NodeJS (222.4345.14)
    Karma (222.4345.14)
    AngularJS (222.4345.14)
```

2. Set breakpoint in code
3. Run code in debugger
4. Get error:

```
TypeError:
  no implicit conversion from nil to integer
  /Users/paulkristoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/debase-3.0.0.beta.5/lib/debase/breakpoint.rb:164:in `set_breakpoint'
  /Users/paulkristoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/debase-3.0.0.beta.5/lib/debase.rb:231:in `block in set_breakpoints'
  /Users/paulkristoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/debase-3.0.0.beta.5/lib/debase.rb:231:in `each'
  /Users/paulkristoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/debase-3.0.0.beta.5/lib/debase.rb:231:in `set_breakpoints'
  /Users/paulkristoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/debase-3.0.0.beta.5/lib/debase.rb:73:in `block in start'
  /Users/paulkristoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/warden-1.2.9/lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'
  /Users/paulkristoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/warden-1.2.9/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
  /Users/paulkristoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/warden-1.2.9/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  /Users/paulkristoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/rack-2.2.4/lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:15:in `call'
  /Users/paulkristoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/rack-2.2.4/lib/rack/etag.rb:27:in `call'
  /Users/paulkristoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/rack-2.2.4/lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:27:in `call'
  /Users/paulkristoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/rack-2.2.4/lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
  /Users/paulkristoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/rack-2.2.4/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:266:in `context'
  /Users/paulkristoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/rack-2.2.4/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:260:in `call'
  /Users/paulkristoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/railties-6.1.6.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:37:in `call_app'
  /Users/paulkristoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/railties-6.1.6.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
  /Users/paulkristoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/railties-6.1.6.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
  /Users/paulkristoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/rack-2.2.4/lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call'
  /Users/paulkristoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/rack-2.2.4/lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
  /Users/paulkristoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/rack-2.2.4/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
  /Users/paulkristoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/railties-6.1.6.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:539:in `call'
  /Users/paulkristoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/rack-2.2.4/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:74:in `block in call'
  /Users/paulkristoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/rack-2.2.4/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:58:in `each'
  /Users/paulkristoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/rack-2.2.4/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:58:in `call'
  /Users/paulkristoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/rack-test-2.0.2/lib/rack/test.rb:358:in `process_request'
  /Users/paulkristoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/rack-test-2.0.2/lib/rack/test.rb:165:in `custom_request'
  /Users/paulkristoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/rack-test-2.0.2/lib/rack/test.rb:114:in `get'
  /Users/paulkristoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/capybara-3.38.0/lib/capybara/rack_test/browser.rb:80:in `process'
  /Users/paulkristoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/capybara-3.38.0/lib/capybara/rack_test/browser.rb:55:in `process_and_follow_redirects'
  /Users/paulkristoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/capybara-3.38.0/lib/capybara/rack_test/browser.rb:26:in `visit'
  /Users/paulkristoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/capybara-3.38.0/lib/capybara/rack_test/driver.rb:46:in `visit'
  /Users/paulkristoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/capybara-3.38.0/lib/capybara/session.rb:280:in `visit'
  /Users/paulkristoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/capybara-3.38.0/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:52:in `call'
  /Users/paulkristoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/capybara-3.38.0/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:52:in `visit'
  ./spec/features/admins/admin_new_spec.rb:46:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
  /Users/paulkristoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/spring-commands-rspec-1.0.4/lib/spring/commands/rspec.rb:18:in `call'
  -e:1:in `<main>'
```

```text
Ruby: 3.1.2
Rais: 6.1.6.1
gem 'debase', '~>3.0.0.beta.5'
debase-ruby_core_source (~> 0.10.15)
```

When I upgraded to RubyMine 2022.2.3. When I tried to run code in the debugger I would get some error I can't remember.  I can reproduce if  necessary.

```text
debase (0.2.5.beta2)
debase-ruby_core_source (>= 0.10.12)
```

I modified my Gemfile to debase (~> 3.0.0.beta.5), which allowed me to run my code in the debugger.  However if I set a breakpoint and run the code in the debugger I get the error:

> no implicit conversion from nil to integer

Comment: [There is no `debase` 3.0.0](https://rubygems.org/gems/debase/versions), so I wonder what that's about.

Comment: You'll likely need to [contact Rubymine support](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/getting-help.html).

Comment: Where did you add the breakpoint?

Comment: You tagged the question with `ruby-on-rails` and `ruby` but I can’t see any Rails or Ruby code.

Comment: If you're using a local Ruby SDK then you don't need to specify debug gems in the Gemfile. Still a code/project sample would be great. You could file an issue on the RubyMine's tracker and share it with limited access:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RUBY

Comment: Schwern-you are right there is no 3.0.0 released.  There is is/was a 3.0.0.beta.5 in the code.  I was very frustrated and thought I would give it a try.     It got me passed the original problem, where the debugger would not run at all.  I forget what the actual problem was.  I should have backed it out.

Comment: Stefan - The whole application is written ruby-on-rails.  The traceback is all ruby/ROR code.  If i should not have tagged it tell me how I know when not to do so.

Comment: I could have given you a code sample but it did not matter where I put the breakpoint, it broke the same way.

Answer (score 0):

It turns that Olivia gave me the answer.  I took the debug gem specified in the Gemfile out and everything started working again.

As you can tell, I am new to stack overflow.  Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Wellcome to Stackoverflow! There is no need to thank the answer. if you want, you can leave a comment on the answer that helped you